# Neater way to have SVN/GIT repos created for each Plesk subdomain?

Tags: svn, deployment, plesk

So I have a CentOS server with Plesk that we use to keep copies of our development work while on ongoing development, testing by clients, etc.

Now I want to go a step further and have a SVN/GIT repo created along with each subdomain and probably add an auto-deploy on commit hook.

This will really boost our development process. I was wondering if there is a Plesk plugin or sth out there before starting to work on this myself. Ideas?

As an extra, a one-click rsync/FTP deployment to an external site would be a nice add-on!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This is now possible with the newest Plesk upgrades (Onyx).
Just use the official Git extension provided by Plesk :
https://www.plesk.cloud/extensions/git

Comment: I'm no longer using Plesk. Could any who has tried this comment the results so I can mark the answer as correct? Thanks!